# Stream Video Url though php

Tags: php, video, video-streaming

I have  created a simple php code to **stream** a **video** file over to PHP server and then to the browser.

Video plays fine but I am unable to scroll through video.

**How can I pass on the range from php to curl properly.**

```
    <?php
    header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

$downloadLink = "https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4";

$size   = '23014356'; // File size
$length = $size;           // Content length
$start  = 0;               // Start byte
$end    = $size - 1;       // End byte

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
    $c_start = $start;
    $c_end   = $end;
    list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
    if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
        exit;
    }
    if ($range == '-') {
        $c_start = $size - substr($range, 1);
    }else{
        $range  = explode('-', $range);
        $c_start = $range[0];
        $c_end   = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $size;
    }
    $c_end = ($c_end > $end) ? $end : $c_end;
    if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $size - 1 || $c_end >= $size) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
        exit;
    }
    $start  = $c_start;
    $end    = $c_end;
    $length = $end - $start + 1;
    fseek($fp, $start);
    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
}
header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
header("Content-Length: ".$length);

$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
         "cache-control: no-cache",
         "Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size"

  )
);



$context = stream_context_create($opts);


$fp = fopen("$downloadLink", 'r', false, $context);
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Remember its not a local file. It is a video url.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your code and any error messages!